# ng-repeat array of objects inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having trouble with ng-repeat for repeating properties of an object when it is inside an array and that array is inside an object which is inside another array of objects like this:

```
$scope.myJson = [{'id':1,'date':2,'nikola':[{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'v', 'name':'b'},{'title':'d', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'}]},   
{'id':1,'date':2,'nikola':[{'title':'r', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'}]},  
{'id':1,'date':2,'nikola':[{'title':'z', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'},{'title':'a', 'name':'b'}]}];


<div ng-repeat='json in myJson'>
  <p>{{json.id}}</p>
  <p>{{json.date}}</p>
  <p>{{json.nikola.title}}</p>
</div>
```

`json.nikola.title` is not displaying every title in every nikola array.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried? You have to show what you expect of the result. What should the HTML render to?

Comment: I actually did but obviously i didn't post the code the right way. The point is that i have that json and i need to ng-repeat properties inside 'nikola', what i do with the result is not important.

Comment: You should accept the answer of @BjørnSørensen below, it's correct with explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't get an output is that you try to output an array as a single value. If you want each value in the array, you use `ng-repeat` on it as well.

When using `ng-repeat` you iterate over an array. As your first goal is to iterate over the main array with IDs this is done with

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myJson"></div>
```

You got this down. Further more you want to iterate over an array on each item. Same as before:

```
<div ng-repeat="subitem in item.nikola"></div>
```

There you have it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myJson">
    <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.nikola">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then access the properties as you like on each repeater.

See [this plunker for a running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oljq6F9MHzK7Ea0P44kN?p=preview) on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `ng-repeat` to iterate the `nikola` object

```
<div ng-repeat='json in myJson'>
   <p>{{json.id}}</p>
   <p>{{json.date}}</p>
   <div ng-repeat='item in json.nikola'>
      <p>{{item.title}}</p>
   </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Have you even tried before writing that ? You have to access `id` and `date` properties of `json` and property `title` of `item` to make it work.

Comment: @Tomisol I was writing it the quickest I could.. ;)